# quotient space linear map implying injectivity

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: 3.91]

In the proof of (b), null $\widetilde T$ = 0. But $\widetilde T$(null T) = 0 as well, which means null T = 0. So T has to injective.

I think it is wrong but I can't figure out what's wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misread the proof of (b): they wrote $\;\operatorname{null}\widetilde T=0$, not $\;\operatorname{null}T=0$.

Comment: I am saying that it can be shown that null T = 0 from null $\widetilde T$ = 0. Since $\widetilde T$ is injective, and $\widetilde T$0 = $\widetilde T$(null T) = 0, then null T = 0.

Comment: Of course, $\operatorname{null}T=0$ i *as an element of the quotient space*  $\;V/\operatorname{null}T$ (which is done for that), not *as a subspace* of $V$.

Comment: But in the definition of quotient space, null T is defined to be subspace of $\boldsymbol V$. So null T should be an element of $\boldsymbol V$/null T as well as a subspace of $\boldsymbol V$.

Comment: Surely, but it is $0$ as an element, not as a subspace. It does not have the same status in each case. Think of , say, $\mathbf Z/6\mathbf Z$: $6\mathbf Z=0$ in the quotient. Would you say: hence $6=0$ in $\mathbf Z$?

Comment: Let's just treat null T as an element in $\boldsymbol V$/null T. since null T = 0, $\boldsymbol V$/null T = $\boldsymbol V$. Also dim range $\widetilde T$ = dim range T by (c), Therefore dim $\boldsymbol V$ = dim range T + dim null T = dim range $\widetilde T$ + dim null $\widetilde T$. So dim null T = dim null $\widetilde T$ = 0. Hence dim null T is still 0 even if null T is a subspace.

Comment: No, $V/\operatorname{null T}\neq V$, because in the left-hand side, $\;\operatorname{null T}$ is *not* an element of the quotient,  but a subspace of $V$, hence it's *not* to ve considered $0$.

Comment: But if it turns out that the only element in subspace null T is 0, doesn't that make null T to be a 0 subspace?

Comment: Yes, if $ \operatorname{null}T=\{0\}$. But you must understand  that, as an element of the quotient space,  $ \operatorname{null}T$ will always be the $0$ element, independently of the fact that $ \operatorname{null}T $, as a subspace of $V$ is the $0$ space of not.

Comment: I think I understand now. So in our discussion above we have chosen a specific null T in our quotient space, and it has to be this subspace null T every time we have the same definition. But there are other null T such that null T $\ne$ {0}. Hence I can't prove T is injective.

Comment: But it's the induced map $\widetilde T$ which is injective!

Comment: Yeah. I know $\widetilde T$ is injective. I just thought that if I can prove null T = 0, then T is also injective, which I confused one choice of null T as the general null T.

Comment: In such a case,$T=\widetilde T$ since the quotient space is just  $V$.